# jquery.selectable with scrolling

Tags: jquery-plugins

I want to use jquery.selectable on a table inside a div which has the setting overflow:auto.

```
<div style="overflow:auto; height: 250px">
<table id="#selectable">
<!-- big table with lots of cells -->
</table>
</div>
```

In the case where the table does overflow I want to be able to select a range of cells larger than the visible area.  When I drag to the edge of the visible area it should scroll to allow me to select a larger area.

This works without jquery.selectable, for example when you highlight plain text inside a div with scroll bars.  But with jquery.selectable enabled, it won't scroll.  Is there a way to enable scrolling while selecting?

Answer (score 1):

Can you copy more code ?

I think you can change :

```
<table id="#selectable">
```

By

```
<table id="selectable">
```